# Possible way to transfer notes from a VERY old iPhone to computer?

Tags: iphone, backup, notes.app

I have an iPhone 4 with iOS 7 that I want to extract notes from. The only useful app that has access to internet is the app store (not even the settings has internet access) and I can't find any computer software capable of transferring notes that supports iOS 7. If anyone has any ideas, I'd be glad to give them a try. Worst case scenario, I take the time to copy the notes manually.

Comment: When you connect the iPhone to a non-Apple computer's USB port, do your files get mounted there? E.g. on an Ubuntu system, my iPhone 8 shows up as Documents (which contains Chrome files etc.), and iPhone (which contains DCIM etc.).  If that works for you, you should be able to copy the files.

Comment: @RayButterworth the only thing that shows up on my computer when the iPhone is mounted is the DCIM folder and it's contents.

Comment: 1) When you say "notes", do you mean notes from Apple Notes? or something else? 2) Do you have a Mac? If so, try imazing https://imazing.com Don't know if it still works with iOS 7.

Comment: @Gilby Yes, I mean notes from the default "Notes" app. And no, I don't have a Mac. I use Windows 10. Does that make things more difficult?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Apple Notes. Yes, Windows does reduce your options. But imazing has a Windows version - try it (I only used with macOS).  imazing has trial period which will be long enough to discover it this works.

Comment: Get an old version of iTunes for windows released while that iOS was current. Open iTunes and plug in the phone. Under devices in iTunes you should see the phone. Browse the application data on the phone and see if Notes is listed. Alternatively you could backup the phone and sift through the backup.

Comment: @Gilby iMazing worked. Once I backed up my phone, it was easy to copy/paste everything to OneNote.